# Oracle Dead Lock

Tags: oracle

I have one procedure, which has below line

```
if(some condition)
    delete from table1;
```

Record Count is around: 10000.

I am facing Deadlock issue while running this procedure frequently. I think some other session trying to update/insert while running this procedure. Could you please let me know how to handle to avoid deadlock issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you could make that a TRUNCATE, which takes out an exclusive lock on the table before it can truncate it.

Or you could use DBMS_Lock to ensure that only one user can run the code that performs the delete.

I'd try the former first.

Comment: +1 But if other sessions are modifying the table there may be other sessions reading from the table.  The `TRUNCATE` could cause those other sessions to fail, I believe with the error `ORA-08103: object no longer exists`.  Of your two suggestions, I would try the latter first.

Comment: I suppose one could ensure they use "SELECT ... FROM table FOR UPDATE OF ..." so as to get a shared exclusive lock so truncate would not be able to get its exclusive lock. DBMS_Lock is a good method though for those not afraid of a little coding.

Comment: Locking that table resolved my issues.